# Using an Exception to Exit PHP Application

Tags: php, exception, fastcgi, exit

My app has a registered shutdown function and it seems there's some issues with that and my method of using an exception with a try/catch to exit the application (instead of using the exit() method due to FastCGI not liking this).

My problem is that if another exception is thrown in the try/catch block that isn't the ExitApp exception, it causes some unexpected results and the end result is the ExitApp exception isn't caught.

I'm seeing this on PHP 5.3.6, going to test it on another version now, but I'm curious if anyone can immediately point out what's wrong here.

```
<?php

// Define dummy exception class
class ExitApp extends Exception {}

try {
    // Define shutdown function
    function shutdown() {
        echo "Shutting down...";
        throw new ExitApp;
    }

    register_shutdown_function("shutdown");

    // Throw exception!
    throw new Exception("EXCEPTION!");
} catch(ExitApp $e) {
    echo "Catching the exit exception!";
}

/**
 * Expected Result: Uncaught Exception Error and then "Catching the exit exception!" is printed.
 * Actual Result: Uncaught Exception Error for "Exception" and then Uncaught Exception Error for "ExitApp" even though it's being caught.
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong expectations from your code. Firstly, if you throw exception in your shutdown function, you will always end up with uncaught exception - shutdown functions are called outside tr/catch block.

Secondly you have no attempt to intercept unknown exception - you are only catching `ExitApp` types. you may want to try something like this:

```
try {
    //some stuff
} catch(ExitApp $ea) {
    //normal exit, nothing to do here
} catch(Exception $e){
    //something rather unexpected, log it
}
```

Comment: The sample code was adjusted to better reflect my true situation. As for catching other Exceptions, that's kind of the point. I ONLY want to catch the ExitApp exception and do nothing with it. All other exceptions will be caught by a global exception handler.

Comment: Your change doesn't change much. Exception is thrown with first usage of shutdown function, not where the function is defined. More over, shutdown functions are called after exit, fatal errors and uncaught exceptions, so again you should not register it as shutdown function. Let your script proceed normally to an end and throw it only when you must. If I understand correctly, you shuold just call `shutdown()` in place where you are registering it as shutdown, but then any code bellow won't be executed, so you won't have uncaught exception.

Comment: It seems the bigger issue here is that exceptions can not be caught via a try/catch inside a shutdown function. It seems that when shutdown functions are called, they are run out of the standard scope. I did not realize that when designing this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your *shutdown()* function is not even in a try/catch block, so it will never jump down to the catch for this exception type. It is going to run *on exit* so you will not longer be in that try/catch block.

On a more spiritual, try/catch is not meant for flow control. I'm not quite sure why you're trying to throw this to cause script exit, rather than just calling your own *shutdown()* method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The code was just a sample mocked up quickly for this post, but you're right on all counts there. Never the less, it doesn't solve any of my issues here. The reason I don't call my own shutdown() method is because if I were deep within my application and I wanted to exit the application, I would have to call exit() or else the script would continue to run. Calling exit() when your app is running via FastCGI doesn't really work well as I explained above. Python utilizes a SystemExit exception and I'm porting the concept to PHP. It works well; however, in this set of circumstances, not so much.